# eliminate render-blocking JavaScript

Tags: performance, pagespeed

I have a strange issue with google page speed insights. I am receiving this error even though I have moved all my scripts to footer, and critical css is inlined in header. Mobile results are very good, and desktop is receiving this error. anyone has some idea on how to solve this?
This is the url for test: [google page speed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=test.bigcat.rs%2Fmirokredit&tab=desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem and the solution! In my original css I have a BG image for top content on desktop. In critical css I have included only bg-color and I wanted to serve this bg-image later. Once I have included bg-image in critical css( in header) desktop results improved and render blocking script error message disappeared. Google pagespeed insights examined the final result picture with the one generated with only critical css, And it found out that the pictures were not similar enough, and That's why it said that I had blocking content.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the source for the URL that you provided and it seems like there is a script tag inside the HEAD.

```
<script>
    sessionStorage.setItem('BASEURL', 'http://test.bigcat.rs/mirokredit/wp-content/themes/mirobuild');
    sessionStorage.setItem('LANG', 'de');
</script>
```

You should also move that to just before the closing BODY tag add the ["async" attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp) to the tag. It will notify the browser to run the script asynchronously as soon as it becomes available and remove the blocking.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Deano. No help with you approach. This script is not render blocking since it is inlined. Even though I moved it to to the bottom, before BODY end, pagespeed insights says the same for desktop: remove blocking...

Comment: @bigcat glad that you got it sorted. Any scripts are render blocking even if they are inlined and you should still always add the async attribute!